# Why won't my multiple elements draw on html canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, image, canvas

In firefox, I'm only seeing one of them if I comment out all the others and comment out or uncomment the background, whichever is opposite the last render.  In chromium I can have two of them but they are both just black filled.  I want to be able to call these as functions inside my js file (once working I was planning to add xy-coordinate arguments).  Is this going to be possible, and where should I go to next? The basic idea that I want to accomplish is to be able to draw these colored circles generated by onClick events in certain places on the page.  Is the problem stemming just from using image patterns rather than color fill of am I fundamentally misunderstanding something about how the canvas tag is supposed to be working?

```
//get canvas and context
var my_board = document.getElementById('canvas');
var my_context = my_board.getContext('2d');

//make red stone pattern
function red_stone(){
    var redpat = new Image();
    redpat.src = 'redpat.png';
    var redfill = my_context.createPattern(redpat, 'repeat');

    my_context.fillStyle = redfill;
    //my_context.fillStyle = '#216263';
    my_context.strokeStyle = '#A9B83D';
    my_context.beginPath();
    //my_context.moveTo(25,25);
    my_context.arc(75,75,50,0,Math.PI*2);
    my_context.fill();
}
red_stone();

function blu_stone(){
    //make blue stone pattern
    var blupat = new Image();
    blupat.src = 'blupat.png';
    var blufill = my_context.createPattern(blupat,'repeat');

    my_context.fillStyle = blufill;
    //my_context.fillStyle = '#216263';
    my_context.strokeStyle = '#A9B83D';
    my_context.beginPath();
    my_context.arc(225,75,50,0,Math.PI*2);
    my_context.fill();
}
blu_stone();
```

Comment: What happens when you use color as a fill style? Running it on FF in JS Fiddle seems to work. http://jsfiddle.net/27tdndue/

Comment: If I only switch out the fillstyle it does not work.  If I comment out the second createPattern it will render both circles.  Can I not use createPattern more than once?

Comment: The necessity of changing the css background for the canvas persists if I use only one pattern filled circle as well.  The repat.png and blupat.png are 25px images I made using gimp. I may just switch to using solid fill since it seems to be working properly, but I'm really curious if anyone knows what is going on with the pattern fill.  I know Microsoft has really pushed to be html5 standards compliant in IE, but using linux this is hard to take advantage of.  Does anyone know if these kinds of issues are resolved in IE9/10/11?

Comment: The load of an image is asynchronous. You have to hook the onload event of the image *before* setting the src. So preload your two images before launching your app. After you'll see if there's still a problem.